# @PropertySource and UTF-8 properties file

Tags: spring, utf-8, character-encoding

Is it possible, using `@PropertySource` annotation, to configure the encoding that has to be used to load the property file?

An example to clarify my problem

```
@Configuration
@PropertySource("classpath:/myprop.properties")
public class MyApplicationContext {

    @Autowired(required = true)
    private Environment env;

    @Bean
    public MyBean myBean() {
       return new MyBean(env.getRequiredProperty("application.name"));
    }

}
```

`myprop.properties` is a`UTF-8` file but, no matter what, "application.name" is interpreted as `ISO-8859-1`.

The workaround is to escape special chars in the properties file, but setting the encoding was possible with the old `context:property-placeholder` so I think it should be possible to do the same with `@PropertySource`

Comment: To anyone looking at this question in 2020 and beyond, I just want to note that some of the information below is no longer up to date. As of Java 9+, properties files should be encoded in UTF-8: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/intl/internationalization-enhancements-jdk-9.htm#JSINT-GUID-974CF488-23E8-4963-A322-82006A7A14C7

Answer (score 16):

It is now possible:

`@PropertySource(value = "classpath:/myprop.properties", encoding="UTF-8")`

Comment: This is really the most correct and simple answer, please accept this as the answer.

Answer (score 6):

`.properties` files are [per definition](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html#load-java.io.InputStream-) ISO-8859-1 encoded. So I'm afraid you can't do that.

You can however use `\uXXXX` [unicode escapes](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se5.0/html/lexical.html#3.3) to represent any unicode character you want. The (slightly misnamed) [`native2ascii` tool](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/unix/native2ascii.html) can help with automatically doing that.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I know that by default properties file are interpreted as ISO-8859-1, and I know that using unicode escapes solves the problem. Anyway, before in spring it was possible to specifiy the encoding of the properties file: I just wonder if this is not the case anymore with @PropertySource. By the way, properties in java can be loaded passing a Reader instead on an InputStream from version JDK 1.6, so if we take Spring out of the context, it is perfectly possible to have UTF-8 encoded properties files

Comment: This is no longer valid as of Java 9+. Property files are by default interpreted as UTF-8 i the Java Standard.

Comment: @RuneAamodt: that is false, nothing about the definition of the load method has changed in a relevant way up to [Java 15](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/15/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Properties.html#load(java.io.InputStream)). Can you point to a source of your claim? I know that Spring (and possibly other tools) interpret properties files as UTF-8, but Java itself didn't change its behaviour. Edit: I found that the change you mentioned only applies to `PropertyResourceBundle` but (according to the docs) not to direct use of the `Properties` class.

Comment: @JoachimSauer https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/intl/internationalization-enhancements-jdk-9.htm#JSINT-GUID-974CF488-23E8-4963-A322-82006A7A14C7

Comment: @RuneAamodt: that page is misleading: the change only applies to `PropertyResourceBundle` and not to anything where only `java.util.Properties` is used separately. `Properties` only ever mentions UTF-8 in relation to the XML format (and I checked both the documentation *and* the code, to make sure).

Comment: @JoachimSauer So the default encoding depends on which mechanism you use to read the .properties file? What a mess. This Wikipedia article is equally misleading by the way: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/.properties

Answer (score 4):

my solution:

new MyBean(new String(env.getProperty("application.name").getBytes("ISO-8859-1"), "UTF-8"));

Comment: Worked for me like a charm in combination with


@PropertySource(value = "classpath:my.properties", encoding = "ISO-8859-1")

Answer (score 3):

> the old `context:property-placeholder` so I think it should be
>   possible to do the same with `@PropertySource`

`@PropertySource` and `context:property-placeholder` are two completely different components. `@PropertySource` registers a `.properties` file with the `ApplicationContext` and `Environment` loading the `@Configuration` class, while `context:property-placeholder` registers a `PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer` or `PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer` bean to perform placeholder resolution. This bean will have access to the the properties in the `.properties` files declared with it and to the properties available to the containing `Environment`.

There's nothing you can do about the encoding used for `@PropertySource`. It will use the system default.

You can always declare a `PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer` bean yourself (with a `static` `@Bean` method), declare some `.properties` files and an encoding. Note, however, that these properties won't be available through the `Environment`.

Answer (score 0):

Or you can use the [PropertiesFactoryBean](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/config/PropertiesFactoryBean.html) that have the setEncoding method. Here an example from one of my projects

```
@Bean
public PropertiesFactoryBean cvlExternalProperties() {
    PropertiesFactoryBean res = new PropertiesFactoryBean();
    res.setFileEncoding("UTF-8");
    res.setLocation(new ClassPathResource("conf/external-test.properties"));
    return res;
}
```

and then you can use in the project with the following notation

```
@Value("#{cvlExternalProperties['myProperty']}")
private String p;
```

Answer (score 0):

Warm reminder:

define @PropertySource with different features in other project classes can give you results that you're not expected.

for example

In Class A:

```
 @PropertySource(value = "classpath:/myprop.properties", encoding="UTF-8")
```

While in Class B:

```
@PropertySource(value = "classpath:/myprop.properties")
```

Class B's annotation may override Class A's, and in this case Class A's encoding is voided.