# How to inject properties with umlauts using Spring?

Tags: java, spring

```
@Value(${my.property}
private String name;

application.properties (saved in utf-8 encoding)
my.name=äöü
```

When I debug my application, I can see the string does not contain the umlauts, but encodings like `Ã¼`. Why? How can I inject the strings properly?
Spring-Boot.

Comment: It seems that, by definition, properties fiels must be in ISO-8859-1, according to this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/25325936/2164109 , so maybe you should save your properties file with the "correct" encoding

Comment: Would I have to encode my umlauts additionally somehow? As when I save it in ISO-8859-1, I still don't get the umlauts correctly.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using annotations instead of the old beans xml files, there is no way to specify the encoding with `@PropertySource`, as a workaround you could use the xml format instead of the properties format for your file. As an example:

Instead of having a properties file:

```
my.name=äöü
```

Use an XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<properties>
    <entry key="my.name">äöü</entry>
</properties>
```

and update your `@PropertySource` annotation:

```
@PropertySource("classpath:/properties.xml")
```